# React.Js with joomla 4

Tags: javascript, joomla-4

I searched almost all possible joomla forums to integrate a SPA with joomla 4. I have a SPA with react ready and I want to display it on the administrator side as a component. The only problem is the bundled react files dont seem to give out any output when added like this `$webasset->useScript('path/to/media/script')`. Can someone help me regarding this issue. The react app runs properly as a standalone but the problem only occurs when integrating with joomla.

Comment: I'm assuming you have registered the JS?  $webasset->registerScript('foobar', 'com_foobar/file.js');

Comment: @GlennArkell I have put it in joomla.asset.json do i need to register it like this too?

Comment: I have never used joomla.asset.json and this is beyond my knowledge, but I would have thought that joomla.asset.json would be related to the core and therefore not a good thing to "mess" with when enhancing your own "stuff".  If I add any additional scripts or stylesheets for that matter within my J4 extensions, I always register as described above and then use.  This link - https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J4.x:Web_Assets - may help you and also by using this process will stand you in good stead for J5.